# Xcode font size randomly changes when testing on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, fonts, uitextview

I am having a problem with a UITextView when building an iPhone app using Xcode 4.6.2 where the font size on a UITextView keeps changing when testing on my iPhone.

I originally set the font size in the storyboard editor and it ran fine, the font size was 14 as expected. Later that day I looked again and the text was bigger (maybe around 20). If I click the back button and select the table cell to go back into the view sometimes it changes back to the normal size. This then keeps changing again and again whenever it wants to.

Having no luck I tried it using the viewcontroller..

In ViewController.h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView * textfield14a;
```

In ViewController.m

```
_textfield14a.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
```

Even after setting the font size with code it still changes size randomly. I have searched all over the web and I haven't seen a single article with this same problem.

Has anyone else ever had this? If yes please can you tell me if and how you solved the problem.

Any help is very much appreciated!!!

Comment: I am also having this problem. The steps provided below haven't helped me at all and I am reaching my wits-end. Luckily it seems that during the submission process/archiving the bug is cleared; I havn't witnessed the issue with a production copy of my app.

Comment: Actually I take it back, I have now witnessed this problem in a production copy of my app. This seems like some kind of apple related bug, incredibly annoying!

Comment: I have the same issue too. I have my textview set to a custom font and it doesn't reflect on iOS 6.1 but it changes on iOS 7. I'm using Xcode 5. :(

Answer (score 0):

delete derived data, delete the app off of your simulator or device, clean your project, restart xcode,

if that doesn't work look at the UITextView to make sure it is set to one property or none depending on your situation, if it is a property search the the code to see anywhere if the font is changing

if not then is it a custom font? if so it could be an error with that font, if none of that works then i would need a sample project to witness the error and debug it

Answer (score 0):

check this...
[textView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:16]]